# Mocking dependency Test passing but Verify method invocation failing

Tags: c#, .net, moq

Verify method test invocation failing:
*.Net Core 3.1, Framework 4.8*

Method being tested: *Code simplify for brevity*.

```
public bool IsValidPhoneNumber(string value)
{
    return value.Length == 10;
}
```

Complete test class (Passed):

```
public class CustomersViewModelTest
{
    private CustomerViewModel _sut;
    private readonly Mock<ICustomerViewModel> _customerViewModel;
    private readonly Mock<ICustomerRepository> _customerRepository;
    private readonly Mock<IMapper> _mapper;
    public CustomersViewModelTest()
    {
        _customerViewModel = new Mock<ICustomerViewModel>();
        _customerRepository = new Mock<ICustomerRepository>();
        _mapper = new Mock<IMapper>();

        _sut = new CustomerViewModel(_customerRepository.Object, _mapper.Object);
    }

    [Fact]
    public void PhoneNumberTest()
    {
        
        string phoneNumber = "123456789";
        _customerViewModel.Setup(x => x.IsValidPhoneNumber(phoneNumber)).Returns(false);
   
        bool result = _sut.IsValidPhoneNumber(phoneNumber);

        Assert.False(result);

    }
    
}
```

Now if I attempt to Verify the method invocation the test fails: *(Assert is removed)*

```
   _customerViewModel.Verify(p => p.IsValidPhoneNumber(phoneNumber), Times.Once);
```

Or this:

```
_customerViewModel.Verify(x => x.PhoneNumber(It.IsAny<string>()), Times.Once);
```

Comment: @Asynchronous What's the point / purpose of your test?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't do this.

What you are doing in your test setup is replacing the method you'd like to test with a different implementation.

In your assertion, you're validating whether the original implementation has been invoked, which won't happen because you've replaced it.

Never replace implementations on the things you are testing. Mock dependencies but don't mock the system under test. Otherwise, you're test is not meaningful.

Comment: re _last paragraph_ - huzzah! Well said.